# No coinciden los tipos de datos en la expresión de criterios

Tags: javascript, jquery, ms-access, asp

Esta es mi consulta a la Base de Datos

```
Public Sub DeleteReservas(dni,fecha)
    Dim SQLDelete,BiaDelete
    If pConexion.State = 0 Then pConexion.Open pCadenaConexion

    SQLDelete = "DELETE FROM RESERVA WHERE DNI_CLIENTE = "&dni&" AND FECHA_RESERVA= '"&fecha&"'"
    Response.Write(SQLDelete)
    Set BiaDelete = pConexion.Execute(SQLDelete)

End Sub
```

La forma de enviar los parámetros es de la siguiente manera:

```
<%
Dim oAccData, oRAreas,id,oRSedes
Set oAccData = new clsData

If Trim(Request.Form("ACCION")) = "ELIMINAR" then
            oAccData.DeleteReservas Trim(Request.Form("DNI")),Trim(Request.Form("FECHA"))
End If
```

%>

```
 <script>
    $(function() {
       
    
        $('#table_detalle').on('click','.remove',function(){ 
           id=$(this).val();
            $("#delete_fecha").val($("#fecha"+id).text());
            $("#delete_dni").val($("#numero"+id).text());
            $("#delete_id").val(id);
            $("#ModalEliminarDetalle").modal("show");
        });
        $('#BtnEliminarDetalle').click(function() {
           $("#inputAccionEliminarDetalle").val("ELIMINAR");
           $("#FormEliminarDetalle").submit(); 
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Con el Jquery mando los elementos de una tabla del html al modal

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="ModalEliminarDetalle" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="TituloEliminarDetalle" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <center><h4 class="modal-title" id="TituloEliminarDetalle">¡ATENCION!</h4></center>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" >
                <label style="font-size: 25px"><center><b>¿Está seguro de eliminar este registro?</b></center></label>
                <form class="form-horizontal" id="FormEliminarDetalle" method="POST">
                <fieldset>
                    <input type="hidden" id="delete_id" name="ID">
                    <input  id="inputAccionEliminarDetalle" name="ACCION" value="">
                    <input  id="delete_dni" name="DNI" type="text">
                    <input  id="delete_fecha" name="FECHA" type="text">
                </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <center>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> No</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="BtnEliminarDetalle"><span  class=" icon-remove-circle icon-white"></span> Eliminar</button>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

y bueno todo se ejecuta normal, el unico problema es que dice que no coinciden los datos y solo en la fecha, en mi consulta la puse como texto, cuando la cambio a un numero lo 'acepta', pero no funciona la consulta ya que en la BD es de tipo fecha

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quizá debas utilizar `CDate('"&fecha&"'")`

Comment: Gracias!, me sirvió así : "DELETE FROM RESERVA WHERE RESERVA.DNI_CLIENTE = "&dni&" AND RESERVA.FECHA_RESERVA= CDate('"&fecha&"')"

Comment: La puse como respuesta para que no quede al aire

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando recibes la variable `fecha` se encuentra en formato texto y la sentencia espera un dato tipo Date por lo tanto, conviertela a fecha utilizando `CDate('"&fecha&"')"`.